# Counting values from a column and grouping and sorting by a second value

Tags: sql, plsql

Let's say I have this table:

```
NAME    YEAR    SCORE
_____________________
User1   2010    1
User2   2011    3
User3   2012    2
User4   2013    1
User5   2012    1
User6   2011    3
User7   2010    4
User8   2011    1
```

I would like to create a query whose output looks like this from this data:

```
YEAR    1    2    3    4
________________________
2010    1    0    0    1
2011    1    0    2    0
2012    1    1    0    0
2013    1    0    0    0
```

Where the values in the numbered columns is the count of how many times that score appears in the given year. This seems as if it should be easy but I am having trouble figuring out how to wrap my head around writing this query in a way that is static. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  YEAR,
    count(CASE WHEN SCORE = 1 THEN 1 END) AS `1`,
    count(CASE WHEN SCORE = 2 THEN 1 END) AS `2`,
    count(CASE WHEN SCORE = 3 THEN 1 END) AS `3`,
    count(CASE WHEN SCORE = 4 THEN 1 END) AS `4`
from TABLE
group by year
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support []. You can use the goofy backticks (`) or much better, double quotes.

Comment: Here is your goofy backticks ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a set of Four values

```
SELECT YEAR, SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `1`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `2`,
SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `3`,
SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `4`
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY YEAR
```